# DOM strange issue with javascript object

Tags: javascript, dom, tinymce

We are trying to get tinyMCE object from DOM in order to set the text but unfortunately when we are injecting the javascript code in the page it is not working while the same code executes perfectly in the Javascript Console (Chrome).

The code is the following:

```
<script language="javascript">
 var testing = 'test';
 var curFrames;
 var curUrl;
 var mFrames;
 var cFrame;
 var editor;
 var editor2;

 window.onload=CodeOnLoad ;

//Javascript that runs on load
function CodeOnLoad() {
  curFrames=document.getElementsByTagName("frame");  


curFrames[0].onload = function() {
  curUrl= curFrames[0].contentDocument.getElementById("the_iframe").src;
  console.log(curUrl)

  if (curUrl.indexOf("post")!=-1)
  {
     mFrames=document.getElementsByTagName("frame");
     cFrame = mFrames[0].contentDocument.getElementById('the_iframe');
     editor = cFrame.contentWindow.tinymce;
     editor2 = editor.activeEditor;
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

The above code will allow us to use :

```
editor.activeEditor (which will return the correct editor object) // Only when we test it in the Browser Javascript console
```

while:

```
editor2 = editor.activeEditor; (the last line of the code - will return null)
```

Comment: Are you sure the editor frame has loaded by the time you try to access `editor.activeEditor`? It looks like you're trying to access objects that haven't loaded yet - you'll need some kind of onload callback for the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to be aware of:

1. When the parent window finishes loading, there is absolutely no guarantee that the content of the iframe's inside of it have finished loading.
2. You can not access properties of an iframe (such as contentWindow or contentDocument) if the iframe's source is loaded from a different domain.

Comment: According the first issue. Is it possible to have another onload function for the inside iframe?

Comment: @salamis one thing i have noticed is that you call your element a "frame" in some places and an "iframe" in others. these are not the same node type. getElementsByTagName('frame') will NOT return iframes.

Answer (score 1):

For your use scenario there is the tinymce configuration setting [setup](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3asetup) plus the onInit handler.

Additionally:

```
editor = cFrame.contentWindow.tinymce;
editor2 = editor.activeEditor;
```

won't work this way.

I will show you how to set it right:

```
setup : function(ed) {

    ed.onInit.add(function(ed, event) {
          // do all you want to do after the editor has loaded here
          var my_window = ed.getWin();
          var my_document = ed.getDoc();

    });
});
```

Comment: Where should I have to put that? Unfortunately, I want to modify tinymce inside Moodle

Comment: the tinymce config should be stored in a file called tinymce.js.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to find that file but its not there. I am using Moodle 2.2.

Comment: hmmm, do you know how to add custom plugins to tinymce under moodle?